# Applying Ampere's Circuital Law to a bar magnet

Tags: electromagnetism

The magnetic field along the axis of a long solenoid comes out to be $\mu_0nI$ using ampere's circuital law, considering a rectangular amperian loop.

But if I try to apply the law to an equivalent bar magnet using the same loop,
there is no electric current through the loop, but $\int \overrightarrow B. \overrightarrow {dl}$ is non zero for $\overrightarrow B$ along the magnet's axis.
What am I missing? Is the law even applicable here?

Answer (score 2):

The solenoid and the bar magnet generate their magnetic fields using different mechanisms, so the solenoid equation cannot be applied to a bar magnet.

A moving charge, like an electron, generates a magnetic field, and a current is just a load of charges moving in a conductor. That's why a current generates a magnetic field. The equation for the solenoid is derived using Ampère's law for the specific geometry of a solenoid and feeding in the current in the wire.

However even a stationary electron has a (tiny) magnetic field due to its spin. This field is always present whether or not the electron is moving. This is called its [magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment). In most cases the electrons have their fields arranged randomly so their fields cancel out and the total magnetic field is zero. However in a class of materials known as [ferromagnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) the electron fields
line up with each other to generate a large total field, and that's what happens in a bar magnet. Since this field has nothing to do with currents you cannot use Ampère's law to calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

The Ampere's law applies to magnetic H field, not magnetic B field because $\nabla\times\vec{H}=\vec{J}$, where $\vec{J}$ is conducting current.
The $\mu_0nI$ in the first paragraph of your statement should be changed to $nI$.
If there is only a magnet and the conduction current is 0, then $\nabla\times\vec{H}=0$,
so $\oint\vec{H}\cdot d\vec{l}=0$, which is consistent with the Ampere's law.

Answer (score 0):

For a bar magnet, there is a 'bound surface current' on its surface given by $\bf K_{\rm bound}=M\times{\hat n}$.  This acts like a current in a solenoid.

Comment: I am aware of your written $K_\text{bound}$. I have already provided an example calculation [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/710836/is-vecb-0-in-an-infinite-cylinder-with-localized-magnetization/710910#710910). Maxwell's equations including Ampere's law can be applied without any problem when there are magnets